# Getting Class names from object

Tags: java, class, jackson

I currently have code mapping a JSON string to a class for an API, however I need code to map JSON to different classes given by class names during runtime instead of one hardcoded class name.

This is my current code:

```
ObjectMapper aObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
aClass request = aObjectMapper.readValue(String, aClass.class);
```

Which works fine.

Now instead of `aClass`, I want to be able to map to any generic class name, however trying something like

```
Class theRandomClass = theRandomClass.class; 
theRandomClass.getClass() request = aObjectMapper.readValue(String, 
                                     theRandomClass.getClass()) //gives an error
```

Any idea how to approach this? Much Appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please update your question with that.

Comment: Parameter type use Class<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class theRandomClass = theRandomClass.class;`  assigns a `java.lang.Class` object to `theRandomClass`.

Which means

```
aObjectMapper.readValue(String, theRandomClass.getClass())
```

Will try to deserialize the JSON string into a `java.lang.Class` object. If it's not clear what the problem is, then note that programs can't just go about creating `java.lang.Class` instances, so Jackson will fail to deserialize the string.

What you needed is

```
aObjectMapper.readValue(String, theRandomClass)
```